# It's likely to happen

Tags: tense

In my book, it is stated that it is only allowed to use the bare infinitive after "be likely".

1 It's likely to happen tomorrow.

2 He's likely to work tomorrow.

3 It's likely to rain tomorrow.

Is this correct, or can I also use the continuous form with 1, 2, and 3?

It's likely to be happening tomorrow.

He's likely to be working tomorrow.

It's likely to be raining tomorrow.

Are both versions acceptable and interchangeable, or are there some rules which state when we are allowed to use the continuous form?

Comment: Please use the "Edit" button to tell what this book is and quote it if possible